# Double inserting records in flask SqlAlchemy connected with PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

Very rarely, I meet a problem that the record that I inserted into Table `Tbl_CUSTOMER` was double with auto ID from Postgres.

I have no idea, but I suspected that it could be caused from postgres vacuum running time. To confirm that, I tried to run postgres vacuum at the same with inserting record, but could not found this problem happened, therefore, I could not duplicate the issue to find what was the root cause and fix the problem.

**models.py**

```
class Tbl_CUSTOMER():
    ID              =   db.Column(db.Numeric(25, 9), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    PotentialCustomer   =   db.Column(db.String(12))
    FirstNameEn     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameEn      =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    FirstNameKh     =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LastNameKh      =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    Salutation      =   db.Column(db.String(4))
    Gender          =   db.Column(db.String(6))
    DateOfBirth     =   db.Column(db.String(10))
    CountryOfBirth  =   db.Column(db.String(2))
    Nationality     =   db.Column(db.String(2))
    ProvinceOfBirth =   db.Column(db.String(3))
```

**views.py**

```
dataInsert =Tbl_CUSTOMER(
                PotentialCustomer   =   request.form['PotentialCustomer'],
                FirstNameEn     =   request.form['FirstNameEn'],
                LastNameEn      =   request.form['LastNameEn'],
                FirstNameKh     =   request.form['FirstNameKh'],
                LastNameKh      =   request.form['LastNameKh'],
                Salutation      =   request.form['Salutation'],
                Gender          =   request.form['Gender'],
                DateOfBirth     =   request.form['DateOfBirth'],
                CountryOfBirth  =   request.form['CountryOfBirth'],
                Nationality     =   request.form['Nationality'],
                ProvinceOfBirth =   request.form['ProvinceOfBirth']
            )

db.session.add(dataInsert)
db.session.commit()
```

This problem does not happen frequently. So, what is the problem, and how can I fix this to prevent it happen in future? Thanks.

Comment: I am also not sure why you facing the issue. On the side note, you can remove `autoincrement=True` it is shipped along with primary_key if in the case table has only one primary_key. Also, I am curious if the type of ID should be string or Integer and if it is a string what it is expected to increment.

Comment: @mad_ thanks for contribution, it is quite strange for me and my client. On the other hand, I could not remove auto id as our app implement id pattern separately. Cannot manually enter ID.

Comment: I cannot understand if you have your own ID then what do you expect db should do with autoincrement behavior on this column?

Comment: @mad_, my app depend on postgres to manage auto ID for record that is to save. The ID pattern that I said is config as the sequence of date/time with two specific prefix letter, eg. 'CUyymmdd`. there are could be many record to be save per day. it is not possible to do it manually. Thanks

Comment: You are getting confused in autoincrement and your uuid generation which is generated from your app. autoincrement is something which db deals with and not your app. Not suggesting to create a manual ID it will still be generated from your app function. Hope it all make sense

Comment: @mad_  thanks for pointing that. I think it should not an issue with ID. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a unique key ( or replace your primary key ) with some hashing function value based on all the values of your row, that may help you to see when this problem is happening. Using this hashing column you will be able to decide what you should happen when your system get the same value ( same hash ). One option, for example, just ignores the new row, keeping the old one. Other, is to rewrite, etc.

The chance of getting the same hash value from different rows is so small that I would not even consider that. Look this thread https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/best-way-to-reduce-chance-of-hash-collisions-multiple-hashes-or-larger-hash if you want to see more details about that.

Comment: Thanks, is it concluded the root cause is because of primary key? I'm not using hashing function for my primary key.

Comment: Probably the root is some threading into another layer that is adding the same line twice. Very hard to figure out the cause of the problem just using the information that you send. I would guess that this issue is not related to the database itself. If you force the unique over the hash and keep the insert as it is, you will get some errors trace that may help you to figure out the cause. What I am proposing is more about dealing with the repeated insert than avoiding it.

Comment: For me, it was a "watched" debug expression in my IDE. The expression got executed on each breakpoint...